# ¿Por qué un ConstraintLayout Chain en compose elimina los márgenes?

Tags: android, kotlin, constraint-layout, jetpack-compose

Estoy usando Constraint Layout con Compose para hacer una aplicación básica que suma y resta números. La funcionalidad va bien, el problema es cuando quiero añadir un margen entre los elementos de la vista, que si le añado un chainStyle de tipo Packed, los ignora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CreateStructure() {
    var num by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val constraint = ConstraintSet {
        val valueLabel = createRefFor("valueLabel")
        val addButton = createRefFor("addButton")
        val subtractButton = createRefFor("subtractButton")
        val resetButton = createRefFor("resetButton")

        constrain(valueLabel) {
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            bottom.linkTo(addButton.top)
        }
        constrain(addButton) {
            top.linkTo(valueLabel.bottom, 30.dp)
            start.linkTo(valueLabel.start)
            end.linkTo(valueLabel.end)
            bottom.linkTo(subtractButton.top)
            width = Dimension.value(200.dp)
        }
        constrain(subtractButton) {
            top.linkTo(addButton.bottom, 10.dp)
            start.linkTo(addButton.start)
            end.linkTo(addButton.end)
            bottom.linkTo(resetButton.top)
            width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
        }
        constrain(resetButton) {
            top.linkTo(subtractButton.bottom, 10.dp)
            start.linkTo(subtractButton.start)
            end.linkTo(subtractButton.end)
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
        }
        createVerticalChain(valueLabel, addButton, subtractButton, resetButton, chainStyle = ChainStyle.Packed)
    }

    ConstraintLayout(constraintSet = constraint, Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "Conteo: $num", Modifier.layoutId("valueLabel"))
        Counter(layoutId = "addButton", titleButton = "Sumar número") {
            num++
        }
        Counter(layoutId = "subtractButton", titleButton = "Restar número") {
            num--
        }
        Counter(layoutId = "resetButton", titleButton = "Resetear valor") {
            num = 0
        }
    }
}
```

No se si al ser Compose funciona diferente, pero usando XML creaba así las vistas y cuando le añadía margenes a vistas encadenadas me lo añadía sin problemas, por lo que no se es un bug de Compose o es el comportamiento que tiene...

Comment: No queda claro cuál es el resultado esperado. De todos modos no se recomienda usar constraintLayout para casos tan básicos. Sería mucho más sencillo si usaras un [Column](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics#standard-layouts)

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem ya a ver se que es un ejemplo muy básico, pero estoy practicando con Compose y constraint y quería hacer algo sencillo. El resultado esperado es que entre el Text y el primer Button haya una separación de 30dp y entre los Button haya una separación de 10dp como está en el código, pero al aplicarle el chain los ignora...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no es un bug pero tampoco podemos decir que sea diferente de XML.

Ya sea en Kotlin o en XML, cuando defines un chain se reemplazan las constrainsts que van en esa dirección. Si el chain es horizontal, se ignoran las constraint `start` y `end`. Si defines un VerticalChain, se ignoran `top` y `bottom`. Por lo tanto tus únicas constraints que efectivamente están haciendo algo son estas

```
constrain(valueLabel) {
    start.linkTo(parent.start)
    end.linkTo(parent.end)
}
constrain(addButton) {
    start.linkTo(valueLabel.start)
    end.linkTo(valueLabel.end)
    width = Dimension.value(200.dp)
}
constrain(subtractButton) {
    start.linkTo(addButton.start)
    end.linkTo(addButton.end)
    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
}
constrain(resetButton) {
    start.linkTo(subtractButton.start)
    end.linkTo(subtractButton.end)
    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
}
```

y eso explica el resultado que se ve en la imagen.

La razón por la que funciona en XML es porque el equivalente de algo como `top.linkTo(valueLabel.bottom, 30.dp)` son dos atributos diferentes:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/value_label"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
```

Entonces el margin no se ve afectado.

No veo que tu pregunta pida una solución pero en caso de que alguien se lo pregunte, se puede solucionar agregando [spacers](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Spacer(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier)) en la cadena

```
createVerticalChain(
    valueLabel,
    createRefFor("spacer1"),
    addButton,
    createRefFor("spacer2"),
    subtractButton,
    createRefFor("spacer3"),
    resetButton,
    chainStyle = ChainStyle.Packed
)
```

Según la dirección de la cadena, el tamaño de la separación se especifica con el modifier `height` o `width`. Aunque generalmente `size` funciona para ambos casos

```
ConstraintLayout(constraintSet = constraint, Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Text(text = "Conteo: $num", Modifier.layoutId("valueLabel"))
    Spacer(Modifier.size(30.dp).layoutId("spacer1"))
    Counter(layoutId = "addButton", titleButton = "Sumar número") {
        num++
    }
    Spacer(Modifier.size(10.dp).layoutId("spacer2"))
    Counter(layoutId = "subtractButton", titleButton = "Restar número") {
        num--
    }
    Spacer(Modifier.size(10.dp).layoutId("spacer3"))
    Counter(layoutId = "resetButton", titleButton = "Resetear valor") {
        num = 0
    }
}
```